# Word/phrase/idiom for person who is no longer deceived

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word, phrase or idiom that describes someone who is no longer deceived?

Answer (score 9):

How about *see the light*?

The Free Dictionary:

> [*see the light*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+the+light):
>   to understand something clearly at last; to understand something clearly, especially after you have been confused about it for a long time

Wiktionary:

> [*see the light*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see_the_light): to
>   gain an understanding of something previously not understood,
>   especially in a sudden insight

"Someone who is no longer deceived" is someone who has at long last *seen the light*.

Comment: Quite so, Rich! A sort of Damascene moment just a tad short of a full-on religious epiphany, what? I get them all the time!

Comment: @PeterPoint Greetings, MF. Was it an epiphany that resulted in *guano crazy*? With you, the hits just keep on coming! What? :-) BTW, what does *What?* mean.

Comment: We should remind ourselves of one of the best scenes in the 1980 movie, the Blues Brothers, when "Joiliet" Jake Blues (played by John Belushi) "sees the light" summoned up by the all singing and dancing Rev. Cleophus James (played by James Brown) in his electrifying sermon from the pulpit. It doesn't get better than that, what?

Comment: @No, it doesn't. Makes me want a cheeseburger, or two. I meant to characterize your guano answer as a PP classic.

Comment: What does 'what' mean? Here goes: it's tagged on at the end of a spoken sentence, a truncated form of "...and what do you think?" We Brits of a certain age and with borderline personalities, try to affect the mannerisms of the fictional Lord Peter Wimsey, a sort of recycled Sherlock Holmes created by the writer, Dorothy L. Sayers. The character is a dilettante who solves mysteries - usually murders, a sort of Anglo-version of your very own Detective Columbo. As you might have gathered, it's a lot of tomfoolery, what?

Comment: @PeterPoint Thanks! Peter Falk. Just one more question. :-) Did you get the cheeseburger reference?

Comment: Similarly, but with somewhat less religious connotations:  'become enlightened'.

Answer (score 7):

I would say they were '[enlightened](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlightened)'.

> enlightened:
>
> 1. Educated or informed
> 2. **Made aware of something**
> 3. **Freed from illusion**
> 4. Exceedingly wise

Comment: This was my gut reaction too

Answer (score 6):

After you [wise up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wise+up) [TFD]

> to make or become aware, informed, or sophisticated.

you will [see through](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+through) [TFD] someone or something

> to understand or detect the true nature of someone or something. You can't fool me anymore. I can see through you and all your tricks. This plan is designed to make money for you, not to help people. I can see through it! I'm not a fool!

Answer (score 6):

***The scales fell from her eyes***

From [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+scales+fall+from+eyes)

> if the scales fall from someone's eyes, they are suddenly able to
>   understand the truth. [Example] When I saw his photograph in the paper, the
>   scales fell from my eyes and I realized I'd been conned.

The origin is Biblical (Acts 9:18). From [BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/acts/9-18.htm)

> New International Version:  Immediately, something like scales fell from
>   Saul's eyes, and he could see again. He got up and was baptized,

Answer (score 3):

After spending sometime trying to figure out what had just happened the **penny dropped**, and I realized that I had been swindled out of my money by a smooth-talking snake oil salesman!

**penny dropped:** (*British & Australian*) If you say the penny drops you mean that you have finally understood something (idioms.thefreedictionary.com)

To which one might add the word **rumble** as in, "He rumbled what was really going in that den of thieves posing as a refuge for distressed gentle folk".

**rumble:** (UK informal) To discover the true facts about someone or something secret and often illegal. (Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 3):

It is more commonly used with misinformed or incorrect than deceived, but you could possibly use [disabused](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disabuse)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you're going for something besides "seen the light" then
"This has been a real eye-opener for me." or "This has really opened my eyes."

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a few antonyms will be of use?

- informed - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/informed
- released - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/release

Comment: *Informed* is a synonym. *Released* doesn't normally have anything to do with the subject of this question, you'll need to provide an example of usage or some other explanation of your reasoning for that one.

Comment: @talrnu Antonyms of "no longer deceived".

Comment: @talrnu If a lie (deception) is a trick intended to make somebody believe something that is not true then to release a person is to give freedom to that person so that he can be relieved from the untruth beset upon him.

Comment: @talrnu Example: "I was in a sect and they told us all kind of things, but thanks to Andrew I was released from the deception we were submitted to. Now I see how blind I was at the time."

Comment: Antonym means "a word opposite in meaning". Both of these words as you've argued them have the *same* meaning as "not deceived", i.e. "knows the truth". Fix this mistake, add your reasoning and example for *release* to the answer itself, and you'll have a much better answer.

Comment: @talrnu Both of these words have the meaning 'knows the truth'. They are the opposite of 'doesn't know the truth'. Reread the question. I know what an antonym means.

Comment: First you said these were "Antonyms of 'no longer deceived'." Now you're saying they're antonyms of "doesn't know the truth". These are conflicting statements. You can keep my -1.